# Technical choices in unmarshalling hash-consed data

Tags: functional-programming, marshalling

There seems to be quite a bit of folklore knowledge floating about in restricted circles about the pitfalls of *hash-consing* combined with *marshalling-unmarshalling* of data. I am looking for citable references to these tidbits.

For instance, someone once pointed me to library [aterm](http://www.meta-environment.org/doc/books//technology/aterm-manual-outdated/aterm-manual-outdated.pdf) and mentioned that the authors had clearly thought about this and that the representation on disk was bottom-up (children of a node come before the node itself in the data stream). This is indeed the right way to do things when you need to re-share each node (with a possible identical node already in memory). This re-sharing pass needs to be done bottom-up, so the unmarshalling itself might as well be, too, so that it's possible to do everything in a single pass.

I am in the process of describing difficulties encountered in our own context, and the solutions we found. I would appreciate any citable reference to the kind of aforementioned folklore knowledge. Some people obviously have encountered the problems before (the aterm library is only one example). But I didn't find anything in writing. Even the little piece of information I have about aterm is hear-say. I am not worried it's not reliable (you can't make this up), but "personal communication" and "look how it's done in the source code" are considered poor form in citations.

I have enough references on hash-consing alone. I am only interested in references where it interferes with other aspects of programming, such as marshalling or distribution.

Comment: I just realized that this question has no "one true answer" and somehow the community wiki brigade didn't complain. I still have a little hope for more references, hence the bounty, but Norman's reference already means a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is not much more use, but Andrew Kennedy wrote a functional pearl called simply *Pickling Combinators*, which appears in the Journal of  Functional Programming, (2004), 14:6:727-739.  There is extensive discussion of structure sharing and how it is handled in pickles, but no direct discussion of how this problem might relate to hash-consing in the *implementation* of the language.  But the article does discuss structure sharing in memory as well as in a pickle, so I hope it is better than nothing.

Martin Elsman had a follow-on paper in 2005 in *Trends in Functional Programming*; the title is *Type-specialized serialization with sharing*.  The article deals primarily with hash-consing by the unpickler (deserializer), not with hash-consing in the impelementation, but again it may be worth something.

The JFP paper is proprietary, but there appears to be a [preprint on Andrew's web page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/fun/picklercombinators.pdf).
Elsman's paper appears to be available through Google Scholar at http://tinyurl.com/yd5tw2b.

---

(In a previous life, I worked on a project to create ASCII pickles that people could read and edit.  I stupidly failed to publish it, but I have retained an interest.)

Comment: I really like Andrew Kennedy's article, and even though it does not mention of hash-consing, it is the best background against which to explain our own solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found one reference on marshalling in functional languages; not sure if it will be useful, but the authors are smart: http://tinyurl.com/yc3hob9

I believe that Matthias Blume and/or Andrew Appel did something on this, but I can't find the paper.  I also believe I reviewed something once for the *Journal of  Functional Programming*, but I can't remember if the paper was accepted or who wrote it.

I suggest you ask Matthias Blume, Andrew Appel, and Phil Wadler if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

Coq V5.10 had hash-consing and marshaling/unmarshaling. I didn't find anything in published form but the unmarshaling steps would be referenced as "reinterning" in the source code. Coq unmarhsaled values and then traversed them in order to re-create sharing, the obvious and only solution when all the language provides is an `unmarshal` function of type `int_channel -> 'a`.